# LowEndian to BigEndian - Matlab

Tags: matlab

I read the bytes in this way:

```
filename = 'random_path';
f=fopen(filename,'rb');%f=fopen(filename,'rb');
if f<3, error('Impossivel abrir %s',filename); end
samples= fread(f,202*4096,'int16')';
```

This file was wrote in LowEndian. Now I want to pass it to BigEndian. I try this, without success.

```
read= fopen('big_endian','wb');
fwrite(read,int16(swapbytes(samples)),'int16');
fclose(read)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should try:

```
%read the data

fid  = fopen('random_path','r','ieee-le'); %ieee-le = Low endian
data = fread(fid,inf,'int16');

%write the data

fid  = fopen('random_path_le','w','ieee-be'); %ieee-be = Big endian
fwrite(fid,data,'int16');
```